# Writing a Sass/Scss function that returns a string

Tags: sass

I'm trying to optimise CSS-related calculations using two custom utility functions in Scss.

One for EMs:

```
@function _em($wanted, $inherited) {
  @return ($wanted / $inherited) + 'em';
}
```

...and another for percentages:

```
@function _pc($wanted, $parent) {
  @return (($wanted / $parent) * 100) + '%';
}
```

...then calling them inline:

```
body {
  margin: _pc(40,1024);
  font-size: _em(20,16);
  line-height: _em(26,20);
}
```

Neither of these are returning the expected `Nem` or `N%` string, however. *(I think it's my string concatenation - i.e. gluing the unit declarative on the end of the calculation - but I'm not sure.)*

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, your problem is the name of the mixin.  I just discovered this myself, but apparently you can't start a mixin with an underscore.

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/B94p3/

```
@function -em($wanted, $inherited) {
  @return ($wanted / $inherited) + 'em';
}

@function -pc($wanted, $parent) {
  @return (($wanted / $parent) * 100) + '%';
}

p {
    font-size: -em(40,16);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ayman, though that's somewhat annoying. Think I'll just go with pc(x,y) and em(x,y) as prefixing function names with a minus could be misleading for other devs.

Comment: For reference for anyone who wants these, but without string output, just wrap the returns in SASS interpolation syntax, e.g.:
`@function -px-to-pc($wanted, $parent) {
        @return #{(( $wanted / $parent ) * 100 ) + '%'};
    }`

Comment: Thanks, Jasmine, this is the best solution—otherwise Sass seems to dump out the calculation+concatenation as a literal quoted string as the CSS rule value!

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, I wrote this function for converting unit from `px` to `rem`.

You can modify accordingly.

```
$is-pixel: true;
$base-pixel: 16;

@function unit($value) {
  @if $is-pixel == true {
    $value: #{$value}px;
  } @else {
    $value: #{$value/$base-pixel}rem;
  }
  @return $value;
}
```

Now, one can use as following

```
.my-class {
  width: unit(60);
  height: unit(50);
}
```